# How can I send a different Scheduled Reminder to recurring memberships?

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders, recurring-contributions

We want to set up a scheduled reminder for memberships that are about to expire, but we don't want to send it to people who have selected the automatic renewal option. How do we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your membership type allows recurring contributions (auto renewal), when creating the scheduled reminder you will see additional options to specify whether this reminder is for non-recurring, recurring, or both:

[image: auto renew scheduled reminder]